# How to push out JSON in asp.net mvc 2?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a response object which I want to convert to Json, but somehow I can't, propably beacuse of I cannot the framework too well.

I'm trying to convert a anonymous object to json but somehow it doesn't go so well. I would preferably do it in JSON than just make a text/plain result.

In my controller:

```
ViewData["json"] = new { Ok = false };
```

In my view:

```
  <%: ViewData["json"] %>
```

In my js-code (ajax-callback) I get back the following:

```
{ Ok = False }
```

Which ain't what I am excepting. I want the

```
{ ok : false }
```

or else js doesn't recognize the property in the object as a boolean.

Or are there some better way to push out json-data?

**EDIT**

I did a method in my controller with a JsonResult instead of Actionresult.

> var obj = new
>           {
>               Ok = false,
>               Message = ""
>           };

```
    return Json(obj);
```

And that's the object I'm pushing out. And like this in js:

```
{"Ok":true,"Message":""}
```

**C# 4.0 and Javascript goes along so well - it is beautiful!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use some library to format the data to json. I would recommend newtonsoft.json

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

You can also return a JsonResult in ASP.net mvc which will serialize your object for you.

```
    public virtual JsonResult Save(MyModel model)
    {

        return Json(new { Success = true, Fail = false });
    }
```

But this ActionMethod will need to be called via AJAX to get the data.